# Javascript difference with subarrays

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am working on a program, and would like a little insight to Javascript difference. In my program, I have a blacklist array which contains values that are not allowed to be in my final result, like below:

```
blacklist = ["One", "Two", "Four"]
someArr = ["One", "Three", "Five", "Two", "One"]
//Desired result = ["Three", "Five"]
```

I found a great tip from another Stack question (the code shown below).

```
Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {
    return this.filter(function(i) {return !(a.indexOf(i) > -1);});
};

////////////////////  
// Examples  
////////////////////

[1,2,3,4,5,6].diff( [3,4,5] );  
// => [1, 2, 6]

["test1","test2","test3","test4","test5","test6"].diff(["test1","test2","test3","test4"]);  
// => ["test5", "test6"]
```

The problem is that I need to compare an array of strings to a specific key in a 3 dimensional array. Here is how I have it structured:

```
Array1 = [collab1: "Name, Someone's",
          collab2: "Else, Somebody",
          ...: ...],

         [collab1: "Else, Somebody",
          collab2: "Thornton, Billy Bob",
          ...: ...];

Array2 = ["Name, Someone's", "Else, Somebody", "Thornton, Billy Bob"]
```

I would like to use the diff class to check collab1 for each index against Array2. Is this possible?

Comment: You need to just compare them or to get differences?

Comment: The syntax that follows `Array1` is invalid. It looks like an object literal, but you wrap it in `[]` instead of `{}`which makes it invalid.

Comment: array1 and array2 aren't arrays, they're objects... you'll have to iterate over them, `for(var key in array1)...`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem `Array2` *is* an array, and `Array1` is invalid syntax.

Comment: @1080p if you just want to know that they are equal or not, I have a solution.

Comment: Ok I may have misspoke. Array1 is an array of arrays occupied with key:definition pairs. For the sake of this question it works exactly as a three dimensional array would, so ignore the types please.

@Rustam, yeah. I would like to know if they are equal. But I can't just compare Array1[i] to Array2[j] since I am looking for a sub-object in one, and just an object in the other.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to compare any 2 objects:

```
var
array_tools = {};
array_tools.filter = function(Arr,fun){
    if(typeof Array.prototype.filter === 'undefined'){ // Допиливание функциональности массивов для IE
        //filter = function( fun  ){ // , thisp
          var len = Arr.length;
          if(typeof fun != "function") throw new TypeError();

          var res = [], thisp = arguments[1];

          for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                if(i in Arr){
                  var val = Arr[i]; // in case fun mutates this
                  if(fun.call(thisp, val, i, Arr)) res.push(val);
                }
          }

          return res;

    }
    else{
        return Arr.filter(fun);
    }
};

var compare_objects = function( firstObj, secondObject ){
    var get_keys = function(O){
        var A = [];
        for(var key in O) A.push(key);
        return A;
    },
    keysFirstObj     = get_keys(firstObj),
    keysSecondObject = get_keys(secondObject);

    if( keysFirstObj.length != keysSecondObject.length ){
        return false;
    }

    return !array_tools.filter( keysFirstObj, function(key){
        if( typeof firstObj[key] == "object" || $.isArray(firstObj[key]) ){
            return !compare_objects(firstObj[key], secondObject[key]);
        }
        else{
            return firstObj[key] !== secondObject[key];
        }
    } ).length;
}
```

To compare 2 objects: `compare_objects(Obj1, Obj2)`. If this will be true - they are equal.

---

**ADDITION**
`$.isArray` is from jQuery. If you don't need jQuery - open it's full source and copy only this tool.